# Unable to route random page in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, routes

I just started with symfony2 hand can't seem to finish the first example, creating a page with a random number.

I have tried to follow the walkthrough from symfony2 here: [Creating pages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html).

The Acme DemoBundle was already installed, so my config_dev already loads the Acme DemoBundle routing.yml which looks like this:

```
random:
  path:     /random/{limit}
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Random:index }
```

(among other entries which works fine)

My RandomController looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Richard
 * Date: 23.04.2015
 * Time: 22:46
 */

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class RandomController {

    public function indexAction($limit)
    {
        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Number: ' . rand(1,$limit) . '.</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that when checking with the debug-tool, it tells me that it can find the route:

```
_random /random/{limit} Route matches!
```

But not from the header:

```
Routing for "/random/10"

Route:  No matching route
Route parameters:  No parameters
Route matching logs
```

Also, even thought the limit should be optional, if it is omitted it will not "match", that applies to other routes using optional arguments as well.

Any idea?

## EDIT

Added output for app/console router:debug:

```
vagrant@scotchbox:/var/www$ php app/console router:debug
[router] Current routes
Name                      Method Scheme Host Path                              
_wdt                      ANY    ANY    ANY  /_wdt/{token}                     
_profiler_home            ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/                       
_profiler_search          ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search                 
_profiler_search_bar      ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search_bar             
_profiler_purge           ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/purge                  
_profiler_info            ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/info/{about}           
_profiler_phpinfo         ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/phpinfo                
_profiler_search_results  ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/search/results 
_profiler                 ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}                
_profiler_router          ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/router         
_profiler_exception       ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception      
_profiler_exception_css   ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception.css  
_configurator_home        ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/                   
_configurator_step        ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/step/{index}       
_configurator_final       ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/final              
_twig_error_test          ANY    ANY    ANY  /_error/{code}.{_format}          
homepage                  ANY    ANY    ANY  /app/example                      
_welcome                  ANY    ANY    ANY  /                                 
_demo_login               ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/secured/login               
_demo_security_check      ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/secured/login_check         
_demo_logout              ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/secured/logout              
acme_demo_secured_hello   ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/secured/hello               
_demo_secured_hello       ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/secured/hello/{name}        
_demo_secured_hello_admin ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/secured/hello/admin/{name}  
_demo                     ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/                            
_demo_hello               ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/hello/{name}                
_demo_contact             ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/contact                     
random                    ANY    ANY    ANY  /random/{limit}
```

Comment: How do you try to access the route? And the limit is not optional, as it doesn't have a default specified (as explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#required-and-optional-placeholders))

Comment: Hi, unsure what you mean about accessing, but I'm using my browser to this address: http://localhost/random/10

Comment: Where does localhost point to? To `/web/app.php` or `/web/app_dev.php`?

Comment: Web/app.php which is modified to run dev environment instead of prod environment

Comment: Web/app.php which is modified to run dev environment instead of prod environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the `/web/app.php` front controller. This loads the *prod* environment, while the AcmeDemoBundle is only loaded in the *dev* environment (as you can see in `AppKernel#registerBundles()` in `app/AppKernel.php`). Even more, the routes are stored in `routing_dev.yml`, which is also only loaded in the dev environment.

In short: The routes aren't loaded in the production environment.

The solution: Create an AppBundle and enable it in all environments and register its routes in the `app/config/routing.yml` file.

Even better: Don't use the prod environment as your development environment. It'll cause lots of problems, including the need to purge the cache each time you changed something; don't having dev settings; don't having access to great tools like the Web Dev Toolbar; having a strange deploy process, as you don't want debug to be enabled in production; and much more.

Comment: Thanks :) That solved the problem. I guess changing `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` to `$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false);` is **not** enough!